# A java Error Exception has occured while trying to execute Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run below code but getting an error message. Any one can help me out here to fix it. Note that I am using `Selenium 3.0.0 beta3` version and `JDK1.7`.Thanks in advance.

**Source code :**

```
package mypackage.msh;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Error :**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Comment: Maybe you should read the error details...

Answer (score 1):

As per [Selenium ChangeLog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG), from Selenium v3.0.0-beta1, the minimum required Java version is 1.8

> ## v3.0.0-beta1
>
> IMPORTANT CHANGES
>
> - Minimum java version is now 8+